# throwFor, next, and nextDouble errors when running my code

Tags: java

I have a few errors when I run my code. I don't understand why I just started receiving these, but I'd really appreciate help. My code is a store that asks the person for 2 types of candy, how much they will cost, and then asks the consumer how many boxes they would like to buy. The error kicks in after I get done entering the first two names of the candies, and it looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Program3Main.main(Program3Main.java:27)
```

Thanks a ton for any help!

```
public class Program3Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        System.out.println("          Coulter's Candy Shop\n");

        // This is the retailer section \\
        System.out.println("--------------- Retailer ---------------\n");

        // This sub-section asks the user to enter the first candies name and price.
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the first candy: ");
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in); // This is the scanner that will collect information.
        String candy1name=s.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter how much the first candy costs: ");
        double candy1price=s.nextDouble();


        // This sub-section asks the user to enter the second candies name and price.
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the second candy: ");
        String candy2name=s.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter how much the second candy costs: ");
        double candy2price=s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("");


        // This is the consumer section \\
        System.out.println("--------------- Consumer ---------------\n");
        System.out.println("Any 13 or more boxes of the same candy is sold at a 5% discount. (We also apply a 6.5% sales tax to your boxes of candy.");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("How many boxes of " + candy1name + " would you like to purchase?");
        int numCandy1=s.nextInt(); // Takes user input for # of candy 1.

        System.out.println("How many boxes of " + candy2name + " would you like to purchase?");
        int numCandy2=s.nextInt(); // Takes user input for # of candy 2.
        System.out.println("");


        System.out.println("---- Candy Units Price / Units Cost ----\n");

        // Variables for candy 1
        double moneySavedCandy1;
        double totalCostCandy1;
        double totalCostCandy1p1;
        double totalCostCandy1p2;
        double taxCostCandy1;

        // If and else statements to make sure candy 1 isn't above 12 (Determine what equation to exe) \\
        if (numCandy1 <= 12)
        {       
            taxCostCandy1 = (candy1price * numCandy1) * 0.0625; // Calculates sales tax
            totalCostCandy1 = (candy1price * numCandy1); // Calculates final total

            System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy1name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy1);

        }
        else if (numCandy1 > 12)// Else to calculate 5% discount on any candy amount > 12
        {
            totalCostCandy1p1 = 12 * candy1price;
            totalCostCandy1p2 = (numCandy1 - 12) * (candy1price * .95 );
            taxCostCandy1 = (totalCostCandy1p1 + totalCostCandy1p2) * 0.0625; // Calculates sales tax
            totalCostCandy1 = (totalCostCandy1p1 + totalCostCandy1p2) + taxCostCandy1; // Calculates final total

            moneySavedCandy1 = (numCandy1-12) * (candy1price * .5);
            System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy1name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy1);
            System.out.println("You saved $" + moneySavedCandy1 + "!");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else 
        {
            totalCostCandy1 = 0;
            taxCostCandy1 = 0;
        };


        // Variables for candy 2
        double totalCostCandy2p1;
        double totalCostCandy2p2;
        double totalCostCandy2;
        double moneySavedCandy2;
        double taxCostCandy2;

        // If and else statements to make sure candy 2 isn't above 12 (Determine what equation to exe) \\
        if (numCandy2 <= 12)
        {       
            taxCostCandy2 = (candy2price * numCandy2) * 0.0625; // Calculates sales tax
            totalCostCandy2 = (candy2price * numCandy2); // Calculates final total

            System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy2name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy2);

        }
        else if (numCandy2 > 12)// Else to calculate 5% discount on any candy amount > 12
        {
            totalCostCandy2p1 = 12 * candy2price;
            totalCostCandy2p2 = (numCandy2 - 12) * (candy2price * .95 );
            taxCostCandy2 = (totalCostCandy2p1 + totalCostCandy2p2) * 0.0625; // Calculates sales tax
            totalCostCandy2 = (totalCostCandy2p1 + totalCostCandy2p2) + taxCostCandy2; // Calculates final total

            moneySavedCandy2 = (numCandy2-12) * (candy2price * .5);
            System.out.println("Your boxes of " + candy2name + " cost $" + totalCostCandy2);
            System.out.println("You saved $" + moneySavedCandy2 + "!");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else 
        {
            totalCostCandy2 = 0;
            taxCostCandy2 = 0;
        };

        double totalOrder;
        double totalTax;
        totalTax = (taxCostCandy1 + taxCostCandy2); // Calculates the total tax
        totalOrder = totalCostCandy1 + totalCostCandy2 + totalTax; // Calculates the entire order total
        System.out.println("The total tax on your order is: $" +totalTax);
        System.out.println("Your orders total is: $" + totalOrder);

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the inputs you're giving to the program.

Comment: Tried running the code and cant replicate the issue. Also, dont use double for anything to do with money, use BigDecimal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're `ENTER`(ing) two times, because you expect the cursor to go on the next line in the console, which won't happen with `Scanner#next`.

Just switch from `next()` to `nextLine()`.
Also remember you cannot add spaces before the actual number when using `nextDouble()`.